# Unmarshal GO YAML to either a Map or a String

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to unmarshal YAML entries that can be either a string or a list of key: value strings (a map as per Go). I cannot figure out how to get this done sadly. I know I can write my own unmarshaller but that seems to only work with structs.

I have the first part working:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Data struct {
    Entry []Entry `yaml:"entries"`
}

type Entry map[string]string

var dat string = `
entries: 
  - keya1: val1
    keya2: val2
  - keyb1: val1
    keyb2: val2
  - val3`

func main() {
    out := Data{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dat), &out); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("%+v", out)
}
```

But the  `- val3` entry causes an error now, obviously. How can I get it to recognise both lists and single string entries?

Thank you

Comment: That's not a [map](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19), that's a [slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7). A slice is a list, a map is a set of key-value pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure what part you're referring to, but the part I'm referring to is definitely a map (key value parts). -- `type Entry map[string]string`. I guess you are referring to the entries part, which is a list. Basically my list can contain both maps and strings.

Comment: I'm referring to your phrase "a list of strings (a map as per Go)".

Comment: Ok, I described that wrong, should be a list of key values parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered in various ways before, but long story short it is easy unmarshall into an interface and then deal with both cases

```
type Entry interface{}

for _, entry := range out.Entry {
        switch i := entry.(type) {
        case string:
            log.Printf("i is a string %+v\n", i)
        case map[interface{}]interface{}:
            log.Printf("i is a map %+v\n", i)
        }

}
```

Comment: Much simpler than what I was thinking (I was writing an unmarshaller). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is just a followup to the excellent @Benjamin Kadish [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48570182/215713), but here's a somewhat more complete version and this uses yaml.v3, which makes it just a bit more obvious. Note that the type of the unmarshalled items is `map[string]interface{}` instead of `map[interface{}]interface{}` in yaml v3.

```golang
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "log"
)

type Data struct {
    Entry []Entry `yaml:"entries"`
}

type Entry interface {}

var dat string = `
entries: 
  - keya1: val1
    keya2: val2
  - keyb1: val1
    keyb2: val2
  - val3`

func main() {
    out := Data{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dat), &out); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, entry := range out.Entry {

        switch i := entry.(type) {
        case string:
            log.Printf("i is a string: %+v\n", i)
        case map[string]interface{}:
            log.Printf("i is a map.")
            for k,v := range i {
                log.Printf("%s=%v\n",k,v)
            }
        default:
            log.Printf("Type i=%s", i)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As, go is static type language, you can't leave `val3` only a list item if you convert it to defined struct. It should be key value pair. E.g. (`val3: ""`) (if you want it empty.)

Here is modified code

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Data struct {
    Entry []Entry `yaml:"entries"`
}

type Entry map[string]string

var dat string = `
entries: 
  - keya1: val1
    keya2: val2
  - keyb1: val1
    keyb2: val2
  - val3: ""`

func main() {
    out := Data{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(dat), &out); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("%+v", out)
}
```

And output:

```
2018/02/02 01:07:36 {Entry:[map[keya1:val1 keya2:val2] map[keyb2:val2 keyb1:val1] map[val3:]]}
```

Comment: This just isn't true, it just means the code parsing the yaml needs to be typed properly. The input format should not affect this beyond making it a bit more challenging to parse.

Comment: Yes, I thought, you want to convert to your struct. So, if struct is okay, then needs to change yaml :)